# How to create matplotlib plot for dates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime

I have a list of dates.

Each one has this format - `datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 3, 22, 19, 54, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`

I want to create a plot. Each date means some action happened at this datetime (so there might be duplicates).

But when I try to generate my plot I'm getting this plot:
[bad plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k404.png)

Also I checked if all the dates are correct. And yes, minimum date is just last month, and maximum date is today.

My code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = { 'Data Analyst']: { [datetime, ...], } }

plt.plot(data['Data Analyst']['DE'])
plt.savefig(...)
```

I want to get plot which describes how many "actions" happened each datetime.

Comment: You could the import collections module then use collection.Counter to form a dictionary (say `d`) from your List of dates which has the count of times each date occurs. Then plot d.keys() against d.values() to get a plot of how many actions occurred on each date.

Answer (score 1):

1. I removed seconds and hours from my datetimes (left only datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 3, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)).
2. Created a dict of apperance of each date ( dict = {date: count, ...} )
3. Then sorted this dict by dates, divided it into two arrays, and voila.

Thanks to user19077881 for the idea.